Android Studio Ladybug: Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 8.0. Cannot sync the project
After upgrading to Android Studio Ladybug, I get the following error message:
 Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and
 Gradle 8.0. Cannot sync the project.
 
 We recommend upgrading to Gradle version 8.9.
 
 The minimum compatible Gradle version is 8.5.
 
 The maximum compatible Gradle JVM version is 19.
 
 Possible solutions:
  - Upgrade to Gradle 8.9 and re-sync
  - Upgrade to Gradle 8.5 and re-sync

I don't want to upgrade Gradle now. What is the simplest solution to build my project?

Downgrade Android Studio, obviously; it's telling you right there in the message what the problem is and what the solution is. If you don't want to implement the solution, undo the thing that caused the problem.

Usualy we don't mind downgrading the Android Studio, but latest AS should have backward compatiability too. This is sort of insane!!

If you don't want to upgrade Gradle yet, the simplest and fatest solution is to downgrade the Java SDK by downloading an older version. Here is how to do it:

Download Java 17:


For "Vendor" choose Jetbrains:


When downloaded, select Java 17



N.B. If after downgrading to Java 17 you still cannot build and you see an error like

module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module

you should restart your machine.

Seems like integrated jbr was upgraded to 21 with Laydybug. IMHO with 4 different Java versions required for [older] Android projects (8/11/17/21) it would be time upgrading gradlew not only to specify the gradle version but also the required/desired JDK version.

There is no Gradle Projects part on Build Tools/Gradle for me. How can I set the JDK to 17?

@CengizGumus, brother, i think you are in a flutter project, open the android folder of your flutter project in android studio, then you will see the projects part in gradle settings

An existing installation of 17.0.11 didn't work for me, but 17.0.12 did, thanks

The Question specifically mentioned latest Android Studio Ladybug and in the latest AS Ladybug 2024.2.1 There is no Gradle Projects part on Build Tools/Gradle.


Open Android Studio Ladybug
File -> Project Structure
Click on SDK dropdown menu -> Add Sdk -> Download Jdk
Select JetBrains Runtime 17.0.12 and save to notepad location (example:~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jbr-17.0.12/Contents/Home)
run command: flutter config  --jdk-dir  ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jbr-17.0.12/Contents/Home

check result: flutter doctor -v:
 flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-arm64, locale ru-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/sergejafanasov/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (5 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sergejafanasov/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/sergejafanasov/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jbr-17.0.12/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.12+1-1207.37-nomod (build 17.0.12+1-b1207.37)
    • All Android licenses accepted.




Please don't repeat answers. If you think the same answer addresses another question, flag one as a duplicate of the other, instead of answering them both.

This also doesn't address the issue, which is about Gradle being outside the allowed version range. Your answer is instead about an incompatible Java version being reported.

@TylerH I think this is correct answer

Man, you’re an absolute legend! I’ve been banging my head against the wall all day trying to fix this Flutter setup after updating to LadyBug, and your steps finally got everything working. That JDK config tip was gold!
